# Android sendTextMessage sends two identical messages on exceution

Tags: android

I've been working on an app that sends SMS-messages. The problem I have is that the sendTextMessage method sends two messages with the same content. How do I fix that?

This class starts the process

```
public class C2DMMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Some stuff
        Log.i("C2DMMessageReceiver", "Got C2DM message");
        SmsSend message = new SmsSend(context, phonenumber, line);
        message.send()
    }
}
```

Class for sending text messages

```
public class SmsSend {
    SmsSend(Context tcontext, String phoneNumber, String smstext){
        context = tcontext;
        phone_number = phoneNumber;
        message = smstext; 
    }

    protected void send(){

        if(foo){
            Log.i("SmsSend", "Sending message");
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            String sent = "android.telephony.SmsManager.STATUS_ON_ICC_SENT";
            PendingIntent piSent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(sent), 0);
            sms.sendTextMessage(phone_number, null, message, piSent, null);
        }

    }
}
```

class to find out what's happining

```
public class SmsSentBroadcastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private static final String TAG = "SmsSentBroadcastReciever";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        switch (getResultCode()){
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Log.i(TAG,"SMS sent");
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Log.e(TAG,"Generic failure");
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Log.e(TAG,"No service");
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                Log.e(TAG,"PDU NULL");
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Log.e(TAG,"Radio off");
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

The output from LogCat is

Got C2DM message

Sending message

SMS sent

SMS sent

So the sendTextMessage is only fired once but it still throws two messages. What to do?

The device I'm debugging with is a Samsung Galaxy S2 with Android 4.0. I read some old threads that sendTextMessage is broken on some (HTC) devices so I tried with sendMultipartTextMessage but it gives the same result.

Comment: Try printing the intent you get in SmsSentBroadcastReciever. Maybe you get more than you expect

Comment: I'm just getting 2x Intent { act=android.telephony.SmsManager.STATUS_ON_ICC_SENT flg=0x10 cmp=com.my.android.app.thisapp/.SmsSentBroadcastReciever }

Comment: What happens if you remove the `PendingIntent`? Maybe `SmsManager` will send the broadcast anyways plus the Intent you specified.

Comment: Nothing (Except that the log messages dpn't show). It still sends double SMS.

Comment: To clarify, does the device you're sending the SMS to ACTUALLY receive two SMS messages?

Comment: Based on the fact that it receives two messages and your Manifest xml, my answer is wrong. Not sure why it would send two SMS messages though. Do you have another phone you can test on? I think you can set up the emulator to send SMSs. Does the emulator send two as well?

Comment: Ye. The emulator and my other devices works just fine. Samsung galaxy s2 with android 2.3.3 works fine as well. Ive made a bug report about this.

Answer (score 3):

Following code works fine, S2 with ICS:

```
void sendMessageGTI9100ICS(String number, String msg) throws Exception {
    SmsManager m = SmsManager.getDefault();

    Class aclass[] = new Class[9];

    aclass[0] = String.class;
    aclass[1] = String.class;
    aclass[2] = ArrayList.class;
    aclass[3] = ArrayList.class;
    aclass[4] = ArrayList.class;
    aclass[5] = Boolean.TYPE;
    aclass[6] = Integer.TYPE;
    aclass[7] = Integer.TYPE;
    aclass[8] = Integer.TYPE;

    Method method = m.getClass().getMethod("sendMultipartTextMessage", aclass);

    Object aobj[] = new Object[9];
    aobj[0] = number;
    aobj[1] = null;
    aobj[2] = m.divideMessage(msg);
    aobj[3] = null;
    aobj[4] = null;
    aobj[5] = Boolean.valueOf(false);
    aobj[6] = Integer.valueOf(0);
    aobj[7] = Integer.valueOf(0);
    aobj[8] = Integer.valueOf(0);

    method.invoke(m, aobj);
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me, why are you using 9 arguments for aclass. When i'm checking number of arguments for "sendMultipartTextMessage" its only 5, so the example above does not find mentioned method. But when i delete arguments 5,6,7 and 8, it finds it. I am confused..

Comment: This is overridden method which is not part of public API, but it can be accessed via reflection.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a small Android library project that solves this issue using the reply from Stipa as well as code to make it work on HTC Tattoo and to make sure the right implementation is selected based on the device.

https://github.com/nadam/compatibility-sms-manager

Comment: This worked for me! Well, the Samsung version now only sends the SMS once. I can't vouch for the non-Samsung versions yet, but it looks good. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with firmware (LPQ) specifically for Galaxy S2 where SMS is sent twice on all 3rd party apps (including Handcent, GO SMS, etc) except stock messaging app. I think the latest version of firmware LP7 fixes the duplicate send SMS issue. Can you verify the firmware version on your phone?

Handcent & GO SMS has found their own workarounds and upgraded their apks to market.

Comment: That is correct. I've made a bug report and as soon as the update is available everything will be OK.

Comment: @daker can you get a link to this report and more information about this firmware

Answer (score 0):

<s>This code will print out "SMS sent" when an activity returns, not when the sms is actually sent.</s>

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    switch (getResultCode()){
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            Log.i(TAG,"SMS sent");
            break;
```

So what's probably happening is that another activity you have running is exiting and then returning RESULT_OK. I can't really tell though since I can see how you set up your broadcast receivers to receive.

Problem was the firmware as reported in the answers above.

Comment: Hmm...ok. The reciever looks like this        <receiver android:name="com.my.android.app.thisapp.SmsSentBroadcastReciever"> 
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.telephony.SmsManager.STATUS_ON_ICC_SENT" /> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </receiver>

Comment: This answer is actually incorrect.  The [documentation for SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) says that if the SMS sends correctly, the result returned is `Activity.RESULT_OK`.  The receiver isn't going to receive intents from activities returning since it's not setup to receive those intents.