# Sms have been sent twice using sendTextMessage method

Tags: android, sms

I try to send a sms using next code, but recipient gets my message twice. I check native app, and if I send sms using it, recipient takes only one message. Test app. code here:

```
package com.test2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;

public class Test1Activity extends Activity {

    private static final String ACTION_SMS_SENT = "com.testapp.ACTION_SMS_SENT";


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        sendSms("Alice","+375295959617");
    }

    private void sendSms(String msg, String address) {
        Intent sentIntent = new Intent(ACTION_SMS_SENT);

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

        PendingIntent sentPendingIntent = PendingIntent
            .getBroadcast(this, 0, sentIntent,
                 PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(address, null, msg, sentPendingIntent, null);
    }

    public static Uri addMessage(Context c, String address, String body, Long date, boolean deliveryReport, long threadId) {

        /**
         * The content:// style URL for this table
         */

        final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://sms/outbox");

        return addMessageToUri(c.getContentResolver(), CONTENT_URI, address, body, null, date, true, deliveryReport, threadId);
   }

    public static Uri addMessageToUri(ContentResolver resolver, Uri uri, String address, String body, String subject, Long date, boolean read, boolean deliveryReport, long threadId) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(7);

        values.put(ADDRESS, address);
        if (date != null) {
            values.put(DATE, date);
        }
        values.put(READ, read ? Integer.valueOf(1) : Integer.valueOf(0));
        values.put(SUBJECT, subject);
        values.put(BODY, body);
        if (deliveryReport) {
            values.put(STATUS, STATUS_PENDING);
        }
        if (threadId != -1L) {
            values.put(THREAD_ID, threadId);
        }
        Uri newUri = resolver.insert(uri, values);


        return newUri;
    }

    /**
     * The thread ID of the message
     * <P>
     * Type: INTEGER
     * </P>
     */
    public static final String THREAD_ID = "thread_id";

    /**
     * The address of the other party
     * <P>
     * Type: TEXT
     * </P>
     */
    public static final String ADDRESS = "address";

    /**
     * The person ID of the sender
     * <P>
     * Type: INTEGER (long)
     * </P>
     */
//    public static final String PERSON_ID = "person";

    /**
     * The date the message was sent
     * <P>
     * Type: INTEGER (long)
     * </P>
     */
    public static final String DATE = "date";

    /**
     * Has the message been read
     * <P>
     * Type: INTEGER (boolean)
     * </P>
     */
    public static final String READ = "read";

//    public static final String ERROR_CODE = "err_code";

    /**
     * The TP-Status value for the message, or -1 if no status has been received
     */
    public static final String STATUS = "status";
//    public static final int STATUS_NONE = -1;
//    public static final int STATUS_COMPLETE = 0;
    public static final int STATUS_PENDING = 64;
//    public static final int STATUS_FAILED = 128;

    /**
     * The subject of the message, if present
     * <P>
     * Type: TEXT
     * </P>
     */
    public static final String SUBJECT = "subject";

    /**
     * The body of the message
     * <P>
     * Type: TEXT
     * </P>
     */
    public static final String BODY = "body";

    public static final String TYPE = "type";

//    public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_ALL = 0;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT = 2;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_DRAFT = 3;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_OUTBOX = 4;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_FAILED = 5; // for failed outgoing
    // messages
    public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_QUEUED = 6; // for messages to send
}
```

Phones: Galaxy S2 ICS,Galaxy S2 GB
This bug occured only on S2 ICS
adb logcat -b radio:

```
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12827]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12827]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12828]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12828]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] onReceive: action=com.android.internal.telephony.gpr
s-data-stall
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] handleMessage msg={ what=270353 when=-1ms arg1=19932
 obj=com.android.internal.telephony.gprs-data-stall }
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] startDataStallAlarm: tag=19933 delay=360s
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12829]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12829]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12830]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12830]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12831]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12831]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
W/RIL     ( 1824): process_multiclient(): EOS. multi client socket(27), errno:11

I/RILS    (19978): SecPhone :: onStart()
I/RILS    (19978): Connected to '7777' socket
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12832]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12832]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12833]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12833]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] onReceive: action=com.android.internal.telephony.gpr
s-data-stall
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] handleMessage msg={ what=270353 when=0 arg1=19933 ob
j=com.android.internal.telephony.gprs-data-stall }
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] startDataStallAlarm: tag=19934 delay=360s
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] onReceive: action=com.android.internal.telephony.gpr
s-data-stall
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] handleMessage msg={ what=270353 when=0 arg1=19934 ob
j=com.android.internal.telephony.gprs-data-stall }
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] startDataStallAlarm: tag=19935 delay=360s
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12834]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12834]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12835]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12835]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12836]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12836]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12837]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12837]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12838]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12838]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] handleMessage msg={ what=270368 when=0 arg1=1 }
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12839]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12839]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12840]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12840]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] onReceive: action=com.android.internal.telephony.gpr
s-data-stall
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] handleMessage msg={ what=270353 when=0 arg1=19935 ob
j=com.android.internal.telephony.gprs-data-stall }
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] startDataStallAlarm: tag=19936 delay=360s
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12841]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12841]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12842]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12842]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12843]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12843]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12844]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12844]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/RILClient( 1825): [*] RecordReqHistory(): token(1), ID(59)
D/RILClient( 1825): [*] RecordReqHistory(): token(1), ID(59)
D/RILClient( 1825): SendOemRequestHookRaw(): token = 1
D/RILClient( 1825): processRxBuffer: status 0 response_type 0
D/RILClient( 1825): processSolicited()
D/RILClient( 1825): [*] FindReqHandler(): token(1)
D/RILClient( 1825): processSolicited: No handler for token 1
D/RILClient( 1825): [*] ClearReqHistory(): token(1)
D/RILClient( 1825): processRxBuffer: status 0 response_type 1
D/RILClient( 1825): processUnsolicited(): resp_id (11011), len(2)
D/RILClient( 1825): [*] RxReaderFunc() b_connect=1
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12845]> SCREEN_STATE: true
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [UNSL]< UNSOL_RESPONSE_VOICE_NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12845]< SCREEN_STATE
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] onReceive: action=android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] stopNetStatPoll
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] overall state is IDLE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12846]> OPERATOR
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12847]> DATA_REGISTRATION_STATE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12848]> VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12849]> QUERY_NETWORK_SELECTION_MODE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12846]< OPERATOR {MTS BY, MTS BY, 25702}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12847]< DATA_REGISTRATION_STATE {1, 00c8, 00c80521, 9}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12848]< VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE {1, 00c8, 00c80521}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12849]< QUERY_NETWORK_SELECTION_MODE {0}
D/GSM     ( 2257): [SpnOverride] getMatchingSpnOverrideInfo, carrier=[25702], im
si=[257027010122629]
D/GSM     ( 2257): [SpnOverride] getMatchingSpnOverrideInfo - no entry for carri
er=[25702]
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmSST] Poll ServiceState done:  oldSS=[0 home MTS BY MTS BY
 25702  HSDPA:9 CSS not supported -1 -1 RoamInd=-1 DefRoamInd=-1 EmergOnly=false
] newSS=[0 home MTS BY MTS BY 25702  HSDPA:9 CSS not supported -1 -1 RoamInd=-1
DefRoamInd=-1 EmergOnly=false] oldGprs=0 newData=0 oldMaxDataCalls=1 mNewMaxData
Calls=1 oldReasonDataDenied=-1 mNewReasonDataDenied=-1 oldType=HSDPA:9 newType=H
SDPA:9
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12850]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12850]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12851]> SCREEN_STATE: false
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12851]< SCREEN_STATE
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] onReceive: action=android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] stopNetStatPoll
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] overall state is IDLE
E/RIL     ( 1824): +handle_modemctl_event
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12852]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12852]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] onReceive: action=com.android.internal.telephony.gpr
s-data-stall
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] handleMessage msg={ what=270353 when=0 arg1=19936 ob
j=com.android.internal.telephony.gprs-data-stall }
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] startDataStallAlarm: tag=19937 delay=360s
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12853]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12853]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
E/RIL     ( 1824): +handle_modemctl_event
E/RIL     ( 1824): +handle_modemctl_event
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12854]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12854]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
E/RIL     ( 1824): +handle_modemctl_event
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12855]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12855]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12856]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12856]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12857]> SCREEN_STATE: true
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [UNSL]< UNSOL_RESPONSE_VOICE_NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12857]< SCREEN_STATE
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] onReceive: action=android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] stopNetStatPoll
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] overall state is IDLE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12858]> OPERATOR
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12859]> DATA_REGISTRATION_STATE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12860]> VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12861]> QUERY_NETWORK_SELECTION_MODE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12858]< OPERATOR {MTS BY, MTS BY, 25702}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12859]< DATA_REGISTRATION_STATE {1, 00c8, 00c80521, 9}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12860]< VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE {1, 00c8, 00c80521}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12861]< QUERY_NETWORK_SELECTION_MODE {0}
D/GSM     ( 2257): [SpnOverride] getMatchingSpnOverrideInfo, carrier=[25702], im
si=[257027010122629]
D/GSM     ( 2257): [SpnOverride] getMatchingSpnOverrideInfo - no entry for carri
er=[25702]
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmSST] Poll ServiceState done:  oldSS=[0 home MTS BY MTS BY
 25702  HSDPA:9 CSS not supported -1 -1 RoamInd=-1 DefRoamInd=-1 EmergOnly=false
] newSS=[0 home MTS BY MTS BY 25702  HSDPA:9 CSS not supported -1 -1 RoamInd=-1
DefRoamInd=-1 EmergOnly=false] oldGprs=0 newData=0 oldMaxDataCalls=1 mNewMaxData
Calls=1 oldReasonDataDenied=-1 mNewReasonDataDenied=-1 oldType=HSDPA:9 newType=H
SDPA:9
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12862]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12862]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
E/RIL     ( 1824): +handle_modemctl_event
E/RIL     ( 1824): +handle_modemctl_event
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12863]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12863]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
E/RIL     ( 1824): +handle_modemctl_event
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] onReceive: action=com.android.internal.telephony.gpr
s-data-stall
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] handleMessage msg={ what=270353 when=0 arg1=19937 ob
j=com.android.internal.telephony.gprs-data-stall }
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmDCT] startDataStallAlarm: tag=19938 delay=360s
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12864]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12864]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12865]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12865]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/SMS     ( 2257): isSMSBlocked=false
D/SMS     ( 2257): isSMSBlocked=false
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12866]> SEND_SMS
D/SMS     ( 2257): isSMSBlocked=false
D/SMS     ( 2257): isSMSBlocked=false
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12867]> SEND_SMS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [UNSL]< UNSOL_RESPONSE_VOICE_NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12868]> OPERATOR
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12869]> DATA_REGISTRATION_STATE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12870]> VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12868]< OPERATOR {MTS BY, MTS BY, 25702}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12871]> QUERY_NETWORK_SELECTION_MODE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12869]< DATA_REGISTRATION_STATE {1, 00c8, 00c80521, 9}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12870]< VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE {1, 00c8, 00c80521}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12871]< QUERY_NETWORK_SELECTION_MODE {0}
D/GSM     ( 2257): [SpnOverride] getMatchingSpnOverrideInfo, carrier=[25702], im
si=[257027010122629]
D/GSM     ( 2257): [SpnOverride] getMatchingSpnOverrideInfo - no entry for carri
er=[25702]
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmSST] Poll ServiceState done:  oldSS=[0 home MTS BY MTS BY
 25702  HSDPA:9 CSS not supported -1 -1 RoamInd=-1 DefRoamInd=-1 EmergOnly=false
] newSS=[0 home MTS BY MTS BY 25702  HSDPA:9 CSS not supported -1 -1 RoamInd=-1
DefRoamInd=-1 EmergOnly=false] oldGprs=0 newData=0 oldMaxDataCalls=1 mNewMaxData
Calls=1 oldReasonDataDenied=-1 mNewReasonDataDenied=-1 oldType=HSDPA:9 newType=H
SDPA:9
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12866]< SEND_SMS { messageRef = 10, errorCode = 0, ackPdu =
null}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [UNSL]< UNSOL_STK_SEND_SMS_RESULT {0}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [UNSL]< UNSOL_RESPONSE_VOICE_NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [UNSL]< UNSOL_RESPONSE_VOICE_NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12872]> OPERATOR
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12873]> DATA_REGISTRATION_STATE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12874]> VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12872]< OPERATOR {MTS BY, MTS BY, 25702}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12873]< DATA_REGISTRATION_STATE {1, 00c8, 00c80521, 9}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12875]> QUERY_NETWORK_SELECTION_MODE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12874]< VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE {1, 00c8, 00c80521}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12875]< QUERY_NETWORK_SELECTION_MODE {0}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12876]> OPERATOR
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12877]> DATA_REGISTRATION_STATE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12876]< OPERATOR {MTS BY, MTS BY, 25702}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12878]> VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12879]> QUERY_NETWORK_SELECTION_MODE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12877]< DATA_REGISTRATION_STATE {1, 00c8, 00c80521, 9}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12878]< VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE {1, 00c8, 00c80521}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12879]< QUERY_NETWORK_SELECTION_MODE {0}
D/GSM     ( 2257): [SpnOverride] getMatchingSpnOverrideInfo, carrier=[25702], im
si=[257027010122629]
D/GSM     ( 2257): [SpnOverride] getMatchingSpnOverrideInfo - no entry for carri
er=[25702]
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmSST] Poll ServiceState done:  oldSS=[0 home MTS BY MTS BY
 25702  HSDPA:9 CSS not supported -1 -1 RoamInd=-1 DefRoamInd=-1 EmergOnly=false
] newSS=[0 home MTS BY MTS BY 25702  HSDPA:9 CSS not supported -1 -1 RoamInd=-1
DefRoamInd=-1 EmergOnly=false] oldGprs=0 newData=0 oldMaxDataCalls=1 mNewMaxData
Calls=1 oldReasonDataDenied=-1 mNewReasonDataDenied=-1 oldType=HSDPA:9 newType=H
SDPA:9
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [UNSL]< UNSOL_RESPONSE_VOICE_NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12880]> OPERATOR
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12881]> DATA_REGISTRATION_STATE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12882]> VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12880]< OPERATOR {MTS BY, MTS BY, 25702}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12883]> QUERY_NETWORK_SELECTION_MODE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12881]< DATA_REGISTRATION_STATE {1, 00c8, 00c80521, 9}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12882]< VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE {1, 00c8, 00c80521}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12883]< QUERY_NETWORK_SELECTION_MODE {0}
D/GSM     ( 2257): [SpnOverride] getMatchingSpnOverrideInfo, carrier=[25702], im
si=[257027010122629]
D/GSM     ( 2257): [SpnOverride] getMatchingSpnOverrideInfo - no entry for carri
er=[25702]
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmSST] Poll ServiceState done:  oldSS=[0 home MTS BY MTS BY
 25702  HSDPA:9 CSS not supported -1 -1 RoamInd=-1 DefRoamInd=-1 EmergOnly=false
] newSS=[0 home MTS BY MTS BY 25702  HSDPA:9 CSS not supported -1 -1 RoamInd=-1
DefRoamInd=-1 EmergOnly=false] oldGprs=0 newData=0 oldMaxDataCalls=1 mNewMaxData
Calls=1 oldReasonDataDenied=-1 mNewReasonDataDenied=-1 oldType=HSDPA:9 newType=H
SDPA:9
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12867]< SEND_SMS { messageRef = 11, errorCode = 0, ackPdu =
null}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [UNSL]< UNSOL_STK_SEND_SMS_RESULT {0}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [UNSL]< UNSOL_RESPONSE_VOICE_NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [UNSL]< UNSOL_RESPONSE_VOICE_NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12884]> OPERATOR
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12885]> DATA_REGISTRATION_STATE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12886]> VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12884]< OPERATOR {MTS BY, MTS BY, 25702}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12887]> QUERY_NETWORK_SELECTION_MODE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12888]> OPERATOR
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12889]> DATA_REGISTRATION_STATE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12885]< DATA_REGISTRATION_STATE {1, 00c8, 00c80521, 9}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12886]< VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE {1, 00c8, 00c80521}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12887]< QUERY_NETWORK_SELECTION_MODE {0}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12888]< OPERATOR {MTS BY, MTS BY, 25702}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12890]> VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12889]< DATA_REGISTRATION_STATE {1, 00c8, 00c80521, 9}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12891]> QUERY_NETWORK_SELECTION_MODE
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12890]< VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE {1, 00c8, 00c80521}
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12891]< QUERY_NETWORK_SELECTION_MODE {0}
D/GSM     ( 2257): [SpnOverride] getMatchingSpnOverrideInfo, carrier=[25702], im
si=[257027010122629]
D/GSM     ( 2257): [SpnOverride] getMatchingSpnOverrideInfo - no entry for carri
er=[25702]
D/GSM     ( 2257): [GsmSST] Poll ServiceState done:  oldSS=[0 home MTS BY MTS BY
 25702  HSDPA:9 CSS not supported -1 -1 RoamInd=-1 DefRoamInd=-1 EmergOnly=false
] newSS=[0 home MTS BY MTS BY 25702  HSDPA:9 CSS not supported -1 -1 RoamInd=-1
DefRoamInd=-1 EmergOnly=false] oldGprs=0 newData=0 oldMaxDataCalls=1 mNewMaxData
Calls=1 oldReasonDataDenied=-1 mNewReasonDataDenied=-1 oldType=HSDPA:9 newType=H
SDPA:9
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12892]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    ( 2257): [12892]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.
internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
```

I checked this solution [Android 1.6 SMS (older application code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015259/android-1-6-sms-problem-older-app-code) and had the same result

**UPD**
bug report: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27024
this is a firmware issue

Comment: I've changed body of question

Comment: Hmmm. Make sure that you're not at all calling `sendSms()` twice. Also make sure, no other code part is sending sms.

Comment: I'm sure in both this cases :)

Comment: @AlexKlimashevsky :can u edit code with where u are calling this method?

Comment: @imrankhan this is a part of a big project and other code wont be helpfull

Comment: @AlexKlimashevsky : i just want to known you are using `ContentObserver ` in code?

Comment: @imrankhan no, I haven't used it

Comment: I posted test app source code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like some phones (HTC Tattoo, Samsung Galaxy S2, phones with LPQ firmware) have a bug in sendTextMessage, but it should work fine with sendMultipartTextMessage.

[Android sendTextMessage sends two identical messages on exceution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706039/android-sendtextmessage-sends-two-identical-messages-on-exceution-how-to-fix)

Comment: Originally this bug was with sendMultipartTextMessage, but I've made a log of tests with both methods